# Return S3 private file as stream

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-8

I'm currently working on a route for a project that I need to get a specific file from S3, read its content, and return as a binary. I can't just use the S3 file url, because it is private and it is intentional (we just don't want the bucket files open).
But the problem is, I want to stream it in a new page to not have the need to download the file.
Service:

```
$file = $this->s3Provider->getFileContents(false); // gets the file binary
return $file;
```

Controller:

```
return response()->streamDownload(function() use($file) {
    echo $file; // streams data to download it, but I want just to show the file...
  }, $filename);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought you are using Laravel, if so then you could return your image like this:

```
return response($file, $filename, [
    'Content-Type' => 'image/png',
    'Content-Length' => filesize($file)
  ]);
```

Another way that I use to return image is:

```
    return response()->file($path, array('Content-Type'=>'image/jpg'));
```

`Content-Type` should be your image type (JPG, PNG, etc.).

Comment: this is exactly what I have been looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Laravel both the S3 side of things and the streamed response can be done using the [Laravel S3 filesystem provider](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem)...

```
return Storage::disk('s3')->response($path_to_file_on_s3);
```

The `response` method on the Storage facade will create a streamed response which is what you desire. If you wish to force a file download you can use the `download` method, or the `get` method will simply return the file contents.